# com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: Couldn't get post build model

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After downgrading from Gradle 6.1.1 to 7.2 and Android Gradle Build tools 7.1.0 to 4.0.1 (by switching branches in Git) I got the following exception in the Run console (tool window) of Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 (when trying to run the app on a device):

`Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: Couldn't get post build model. Module: My_App.app Variant: debug`

The Grade build runs successfully but the app won't be installed in the device.

Comment: Have you found the solution?if yes please share

Comment: Yes solution is posted below.

Answer (score 6):

I have faced this issue when i upgrade to android studio Dolphin. So for me this workaround was to delete the existing app configuration from Run/Debug Configurations.
[image]

After that add new configuration by clicking the left top + icon and then add Android App.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio run `File > Invalidate Caches ...` and restart (you don't need to select the optional "Clear file system cache and Local History"). Just to be sure, also run `Build > Clean Project`.

Comment: clean project, rebuild, works for me

Answer (score 0):

You should change build variant. Build > Select build variant and change it debug to release.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]